# Kolmogorov's Truncation Lemma (ii)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation, characteristic-functions

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

How exactly do we have the part in the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ box?

**What I tried:**

$$E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{|X| > n} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1_{|X| > n} + \sum_{n=\lfloor|X|\rfloor}^{\infty} 1_{\lfloor|X|\rfloor > n} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1_{\Omega} + \sum_{n=\lfloor|X|\rfloor}^{\infty} 1_{\emptyset} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1 + \sum_{n=\lfloor|X|\rfloor}^{\infty} 0 \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1 \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1}} \color{green}{1} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ (\color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} - \color{blue}{1} + 1) (\color{green}{1}) \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ (\color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1}) (\color{green}{1}) \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1 \right]$$

$$ \le E\left[ |X|  \right]$$

Is that right?

Comment: Essentially yes, but you seem to be overthinking it.

Comment: @StefanHansen post as answer? Elaborate however you like

Comment: @Did I edited my question and answer. Please remove the downvotes you made, if any

Comment: Yeah, sure... Answer still wrong. Checking simple cases would avoid these pantomimes.

Comment: @Did Which part is wrong?

Comment: Which part of "Checking simple cases" do you fail to understand?

Comment: @Did I believe I checked cases.

Comment: Right, so you are ultra confident that the upper bound in your "answer" is correct. So, if $X=\pi$ almost surely, then the expectation of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{|X|>n}=3$ is less than the expectation of $\lfloor|X|\rfloor-1=2$. Rrrright... I see. You checked cases. Indeed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{|X| > n} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1_{|X| > n} + \sum_{n=\lfloor|X|\rfloor}^{\infty} 1_{\lfloor|X|\rfloor > n} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1_{\Omega} + \sum_{n=\lfloor|X|\rfloor}^{\infty} 1_{\emptyset} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1 + \sum_{n=\lfloor|X|\rfloor}^{\infty} 0 \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} 1 \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \sum_{n=\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1}} \color{green}{1} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ (\color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} - \color{blue}{1} + 1) (\color{green}{1}) \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ (\color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1}) (\color{green}{1}) \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \color{red}{\lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1} \right]$$

$$ = E\left[ \lfloor|X|\rfloor - 1 \right]$$

$$ \le E\left[ |X|  \right]$$