# Kolmogorov Truncation Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...$ are IID RVs each with the same distribution as $X$, where $E[|X|]<\infty$. Define $$Y_n:=\begin{cases}
X_n,  & \text{if $|X_n|\leq n$} \\
0, & \text{if $|X_n|> n$}
\end{cases}$$, I should show that $P(X_n=Y_n \text{ eventually})=1$. One approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814822/kolmogorovs-truncation-lemma-ii) uses the Borel-Cantelli Lemma. However, I tried to prove it as follows:

$$P(\text{lim sup}_n\{Y_n\neq X_n\})=P(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{|X_n|>n\})=P(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{|X|>n\})$$. The last equality arises by the assumption that $X$ has the same distribution. Further, let denote $A_n:=\{|X|>n\}$, the $A_n$ is a decreasing series $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ and hence $\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_n=A_n$. Using this result, $$P(\bigcap_nA_n)=\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}P(A_n).$$
Now we want to estimate the $P(A_n)$ by using Markov-type inequality:$$nP(\{|X|>n\})\leq E[|X|]<\infty$$. The last inequality arises from the assumption. Hence, $0\leq\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)\leq0$, which closes the argument.

Is this right? Why is necessary to use Borel-Cantelli in the link?

Comment: @kimchilover What do you mean? I should show that the both random variable are equal almost surely and I showed that it's complement is zero. Is this your question?

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks for pointing out. I messed up the sub-indices. Is corrected.

Comment: Thanks!  I've removed my comments.

Comment: The step $$P(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{|X_n|>n\}) = P(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{|X|>n\})$$ is (unneeded and) squarely wrong.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your answer! Is it because that the random variables have the same distribution doesn't imply that their limit should also have same distribution? So I should better write $$P(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{|X_n|>n\})=\text{lim}_{n \to \infty}P(\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{|X_n|>n\}).$$ From this point, can I still argue that $A'_n:=\{|X_n|>n\}$ is decreasing and use the property $\bigcup_{k \geq n}A'_n=A'_n$?

Comment: @quallenjäger The issue is that just cause two events have the same probability does not mean they're the same event. In fact, it's quite unclear what the "event" $\{|X|>n\}$ even is. Also you said you corrected your indices, but it is still wrong. We should have something like $$P(\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\ge n}\{X_k > k\}) =P(\bigcap_n A_n).$$ The part $\bigcup_{k\ge n}A'_n = A'_n$ is just nonsense (and it should be $A'_k$). You do want to show $P(A_n)\to 0$ and the way to do that is $$ P(A_n) = P(\bigcup_{k\ge n}\{X_k>k\}) \le \sum_{k\ge n}P(X_k>k),$$ which is exactly the proof of Borel Cantelli.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the clarification. Very helpful.